# HOW can i import table from mysql to Hive?

Tags: sqoop

```
use testhadoop;

CREATE TABLE employee(
  empid INT(2),
  empname varchar(20),
  salray int (6)
);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES
  (1,'emp1',15000),
  (1,'emp1',15000),
  (2,'emp2',12200),
  (3,'emp3',99999),
  (4,'emp4',17687),
  (5,'emp5',45788);
```

---

```
cd $SQOOP_HOME

bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoop --username root -P --table employee --hive-import -verbose -m 1
```

I am getting the following error, can you please provide solution for this

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 1
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:364)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:314)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:415)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using -verbose replace it with --verbose

bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoop --username root -P --table employee --hive-import --verbose -m 1

Answer (score 0):

Verbose option is used to display detailed execution details on screen.

Verbose is not mandatory, you can run the command without verbose option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the hive table is not created,

```
bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoop --username  --password --table employee --hive-table hive_employee --create-hive-table --hive-import -m 1 --verbose
```

The above command will create the hive table named *"hive_employee"* and imports the mysql data into it. Fails if the table of same name already exists.

Refer [here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive) for explanation of hive options.